# PHP scheduled email alerts using preselected timezone

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I've been searching alot and I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a PHP web page where I can schedule email alerts at specific times. I select the date and time of when the alert is to be sent. This is stored in MySQL table in UNIX format. I have a job that executes every 15 minutes and sends the emails if the date+time is in the past - this all works perfectly except I need to extend it for my USA colleagues. I am based in Ireland so I will need to manage the different timezones all across the US. I am planning on adding a select list of timezones that the user will have to select once they register...at least thats a start. Managing timezones is fine because I reckon all I need to do is minus the time different from the server time and then save the date time in unix format. DST is a different issue tho - does anyone have any ideas on how to overcome this?

I have read that using UTC as the base time but even if that is the case wont I still have the same issue?

Thanks a mil!

Comment: Store the datetimes in UTC. Allow users to select their timezone. Use PHP's [built in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) timezone calculations to get the offset when your script runs. Then you can do the math necessary to see if you're emails should be sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your times are already in UNIX timestamp format so all you need is to calculate time difference (offset) of user. For example Ireland is in `UTC/UTC+1` timezone. So all you need is to do the math like **james_t** mentioned in his comment. If you need user from Ireland to get an email in `9:00pm UTC+1` you have to send it in `8:00pm UTC`. So what's an idea?

Allow users to select timezone which means they select offset from UTC. Keep it somewhere in database (your users table or some other table, doesn't matter).

Convert offset in seconds:

```
$delta_time = -1 * $offset * 3600
```

Then calculate your trigger-time:

```
$trigger_time = time() + $delta_time;
```

Now you have time when your email sender can fire in right moment depending on user's timezone settings.

For example:

```
$offset = 1; // summer in Ireland
$server_time = time(); // at the moment 1350509127
$delta_time = -1 * $offset * 3600; // -3600
$trigger_time = $server_time + $delta_time; // 1350505527
```

All you need is to compare `$trigger_time` with UNIX timestamp from your database and decide to send an email (or not).

Ofc, it's not bad idea to use [PHP timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) instead of pure +/- offset and stay updated when DST changes apply on certain locations.

Make some test, this is not that hard.

This is just a general idea, not complete working solution.

### Update:

To calculate time-difference in seconds between any two timezones you can use something like this:

### function delta_offset()

```
  function delta_offset($server_timezone, $user_timezone) {
    $dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($server_timezone));
    $offset_server = $dt->getOffset();
    $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($user_timezone));
    $offset_user = $dt->getOffset();
    return $offset_user - $offset_server;
    }
```

To get an offset in seconds:

```
  $server_tz = "Europe/London";
  $user_tz = "America/New_York";
  $offset = delta_offset($server_tz, $user_tz);  // offset in sec.
```

Create some output:

```
  $dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  echo "<pre>UTC date/time: " . $dt->format('l, F jS, <b>H:i:s</b>') . "\n";
  $dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($server_tz));
  echo "London date/time: " . $dt->format('l, F jS, <b>H:i:s</b>') . "\n";
  $dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($user_tz));
  echo "New York date/time: " . $dt->format('l, F jS, <b>H:i:s</b>') . "\n\n";
  echo "Time difference between London (UK) and New York (USA) is: <b>$offset_h</b> ($offset s)</pre>";
```

Output in browser (in moment of writing this post):

```
UTC date/time: Wednesday, October 17th, 22:32:27
London date/time: Wednesday, October 17th, 23:32:27
New York date/time: Wednesday, October 17th, 18:32:27

Time difference between London (UK) and New York (USA) is: -5:00 (-18000 s)
```

In this case offset is -5 hours (-18000 seconds) but it automatically changes if DST rules change for any of timezones given as function-arguments.

**Delta-offset** provides information how much earlier or later you have to send an email to user in different timezone and all you need now is to do simple `+/- delta-offset` with your email-sender's scheduler.

Hope this may help you to get right solution for your problem.

### Update #2 - Example (theory)

Imagine this situation.

Your current server-time is `X` and its `7:00pm` at the moment in Ireland. I live in Serbia and we have same DST rules but I’m one hour after (UTC+1/UTC+2). Difference between your and my time is `+3600 seconds` (1 hour).

Now you have to send an email to me in `10:00pm` (it’s `9:00pm in Ireland`).

- Current time is `X`.
- Delta-offset is `-1 * +3600 = -3600` (delta-offset multiplied with -1).
- Sending time on your location in 10:00 pm is `X + 10800` (3 hours later).
- Sending time  on my location in 10 pm is `X + 10800 + delta-offset = X + 7200` (2 hours later).

Formula to check if actual time is equal or greater than trigger-time (sending time) is:

```
current_timestamp >= trigger_timestamp + delta_offset
```

where delta-offset from `delta_offset()` function must be multiplied with `-1` to use in formula.

Now you can send email when you want and be sure it will be sent using user's local time (ofc, if user timezone settings are correct).

**Note:** Difference from this example (Serbia - Ireland = +1 hour) is different during DST changes which means that 1 hour every year we're in same timezone (`0 delta-offset`), and one hour we have `+2 hours delta-offset`. This is possible because DST changes are applied 1 hour earlier in Serbia so when our time is changed +1 you have to wait 60 minutes before same change applies to Ireland-time *then we're +2) and same thing when we bring back clock to normal time (0 difference).

Comment: hi james_t and Wh1T3h4Ck5, thanks so much for your responses especially to Wh1T3h4Ck5 for the amount of detail. It does certainly look like the route I should take...thanks again guys!

Comment: you're welcome mate. I've put another update in addition to my answer to help you understand, take a look.